# How to stitch planar images?

Tags: image-processing, photo-stitching

Suppose I have perfect planar fragments of a big image. How to stitch them automatically?

Software should detect edge features but should not expect camera calibration.

Comment: Try something like `hugin`.

Comment: I tried it, but it asks lens data for each image (annoying) and does not search for control points automatically.

Comment: Of course it should know lens data for geometry guess. But you can manually set it.

Comment: The questions this one supposedly duplicates say nothing about planar stitching, nor did I find anything in the answers to them that make me think this question should have been closed.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, the provided duplicates provide no solution.